# error: expected '#pragma omp' clause before 'num_thread'

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

new to openmp. My environment as follows:

```
ubuntu 16.04TLS
gcc 7.3.0
```

My code as follows:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_thread(2)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the command:

```
gcc -fopenmp main.cpp -o main
```

the error shows:

> error: expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause before ‘num_thread’
>
> #pragma omp parallel num_thread(2)

what should i do to solve this problem? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to explicitly specify the number of threads in OpenMP you have to use `num_threads()` with  an `s`:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```